# Terminal won't recognize recently installed CLIs

Tags: 16.04, command-line, laravel

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm trying to install vue-cli by running:

```
npm install -g vue-cli
```

This is the output:

```
npm WARN deprecated coffee-script@1.12.7: CoffeeScript on NPM has moved to "coffeescript" (no hyphen)
/home/gabriel/.npm-global/bin/vue-init -> /home/gabriel/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/vue-cli/bin/vue-init
/home/gabriel/.npm-global/bin/vue -> /home/gabriel/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/vue-cli/bin/vue
/home/gabriel/.npm-global/bin/vue-list -> /home/gabriel/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/vue-cli/bin/vue-list
+ vue-cli@2.9.6
updated 2 packages in 18.669s
```

(I ran the command once more to get the output, that's why it says updated)

However, the terminal won't recognize the command "vue":

```
No command 'vue' found, did you mean:
 Command 'vpe' from package 'texlive-latex-extra' (universe)
vue: command not found
```

The directory /home/gabriel/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/vue-cli/bin/vue-init contains:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 gabriel gabriel  380 jun  4 22:47 vue*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 gabriel gabriel  309 oct  1  2017 vue-build*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 gabriel gabriel  438 may 31 12:00 vue-create*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 gabriel gabriel 3.9K feb  4  2018 vue-init*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 gabriel gabriel  775 oct  1  2017 vue-list*
```

This actually happens whenever I'm trying to install any new CLI. It happens as well with the Laravel installer, if I try to run the install command it tells me it's already installed but, as it happened with vue-cli, it won't recognized the command:

```
gabriel@gabriel /v/w/h/test> composer global require "laravel/installer"
Changed current directory to /home/gabriel/.config/composer
You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.org/xdebug
Using version ^2.0 for laravel/installer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
gabriel@gabriel /v/w/h/test> laravel new app
laravel: command not found
```

This didn't use to happen. Since I was able to install composer and npm successfully, for instance.

What could be causing this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Edit.- I tried to add environmental variable to PATH in ~/.profile, but this didn't seem to work either. The file looks like this:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/vue-cli/bin:$PATH"
# Ubuntu make installation of Ubuntu Make binary symlink
PATH=/home/gabriel/.local/share/umake/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I don't know npm/java, but it looks like to me you're trying to run them from SH, and they are not located in your $PATH.  If you type `whereis vue` I suspect you'll get no output, as you've not put them in searched directories, or added the located directories to your path so they can be found.

Comment: See update in question, please